# Does linear regression form a subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, regression, machine-learning

The author writes *Given a vector of inputs $X^T = (X_1, \dots ,X_p)$, we can predict an output $Y$ via $$ \hat{Y} = \beta_0 + \sum_{j = 1}^p X_j \beta_j$$*

He goes on to note that if we include a 1 in the vector $X$, making it a $p+1$ dimensional vector, we can write the regression as an inner product $\hat{Y} = X^T\beta$, and this is a subspace.  If the constant is not included, it forms an affine set.

I'm not convinced that $X^T\beta$ forms a subspace of $X^T \in \mathbb{R}^{p+1}$, mostly because $\vec{0} \not \in X^T\beta$.  Unless the author thinks that $X^T\beta$ is a subspace in beta, in which case I agree.

Maybe someone could clarify for me.  The book is *Elements of Statistical Learning*, page 12.

Comment: "And this is a subspace". Do we have any idea which **set** it is that is supposed to be a subspace here?